# Why does the value of a simple computation give a wrong result in java? Does it overflow?

Tags: java

This is how my code looks:

```
double test = (21757952*100)/63290718;
Log.i("TAH", "test = " +test);
```

It shows "test = `-33`"

Why is the value wrong?
Is it overflow ?

Comment: Yes it is overflow. Convert one of the values between brackets to double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integer overflow happening there. Since you are not telling that those are doubles.

try

```
double test = (21757952.0 * 100) / 63290718;
System.out.println(test);
```

Making a value (or all values) `double` (*or indicating that double*) make sure that the operation should done with doubles.

Answer (score 2):

```
 double test = (21757952*100)/63290718;
```

values in 21757952,100, 63290718 should use as double. Currently they are `int` values.

You can try as follows.

```
   double test = (21757952.0*100.0)/63290718.0;
   System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
double test = (double)21757952*100/63290718;
```

Comment: Though correct answer, avoid casting where ever you can and add literals indicating the data type. That is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of it.